# Only the top most tr/td getting affected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am having a table, where in the data is getting fetched dynamically from the database. The issue I am facing is no matter which row I try to check, the result occurs only in the first tr/td. I will post the code for the table and the JS below:

```html
<?php 
foreach( $paid_products as $product) 
{ 
    $price = empty($product->sales_price)?$product->price:$product->sales_price;
    $ingredients = empty($product->ingredients)?$product->ingredients:$product->ingredients;
    $quantity =  empty($product->quantity)?0:$product->quantity;
    $discount = empty($product->discount)?0:($product->discount);
    $discount_amount = empty($product->discount_amount)?0:($product->discount_amount);
    $discounted_amount = empty($product->discounted_amount)?0:($product->discounted_amount);
    $total_quantity = empty($product->product_quantity)?0:($product->product_quantity);
    $product_ordered = empty($product->product_ordered)?0:($product->product_ordered);
    $quantity_available = $total_quantity - $product_ordered;
    $subtotal = $price*$quantity; ?>

    <tr class="calc">
        <td title="Ingredients: <?php echo $product->ingredients; ?>"><?php echo $product->name; ?></td>
        <td title="Reason for price change:" <?php echo !empty($product->product_message)?' '.$product->product_message.'"':''; ?>>
            <input style="width:100%; text-align:right; padding-right:5px;"  type="text" name="paid_product_price[]" class="price paidShowMessage" value="<?php echo $price; ?>">
            <input type="text" class="paid_product_message" name="paid_product_message[]" value="<?php echo $product->product_message; ?>">
        </td>
        <td title="Reason for discount:" <?php echo !empty($product->product_dmessage)?' '.$product->product_dmessage.'"':''; ?>>
            <input style="width:100%; text-align:right; padding-right:5px;"  type="text" name="paid_product_dscnt[]" class="dscnt spidEdit paidShowDMessage" value="<?php echo $discount; ?>">
            <!--<input type="text" name="paid_product_dscnt[]" class="dscnt spidEdit" value="<?php //echo $discount; ?>" data-min="0"  data-max="<?php //echo $product->max; ?> ">-->
            <input type="text" class="paid_product_dmessage" name="paid_product_dmessage[]" value="<?php echo $product->product_dmessage; ?>">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="paid_product_dscnt_amt[]" class="dscnt_amt spidEdit" value="<?php echo $discount_amount; ?>" data-min="0"  data-max="<?php echo $product->max; ?> ">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="paid_product_id[]" value="<?php echo $product->product_id; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $quantity_available; ?>" class="qa">                
            <input  type="text"  name="paid_product_qty[]" onkeyup="backOrder()" class="qty spinEdit" value="<?php echo $quantity; ?>" data-min="0"  data-max="<?php echo $product->max; ?>" >
        </td>
        <!--data-min="0"-->
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="bo spidEdit" id="quav" value="<?php echo $quantity_available;?>">
        </td>
        <td title="Back Order Quantity:">
            <input style="width:100%; text-align:right; padding-right:5px;" id="qupe" type="text" name="paid_product_bo[]" class="boShowMessage" value="">
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:5px;">
            <input type="text" class="total" name="paid_product_dscnted_amt[]" value="<?php echo $discounted_amount; ?>" readonly>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php 
} ?>
```

```js
function backOrder() {
    var quav = document.getElementById("quav");
    var qupe = document.getElementById("qupe");
    qupe.value = -1 * (quav.value);
}
```

Comment: You should have only one item with given id on the page.

Comment: You need to append each row to a table otherwise it will overwrite every single time and also make sure you have unique ids for all elements.

Comment: When asking for help with HTML/CSS/JS, don't post PHP code. Post the resulting HTML/CSS/JS code -- e.g., what the browser sees.

Comment: Thanks for the info guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <?php 
        $count = 0;
        foreach( $paid_products as $product){ 
            $price = empty($product->sales_price)?$product->price:$product->sales_price;
            $ingredients = empty($product->ingredients)?$product->ingredients:$product->ingredients;
            $quantity =  empty($product->quantity)?0:$product->quantity;
            $discount = empty($product->discount)?0:($product->discount);
            $discount_amount = empty($product->discount_amount)?0:($product->discount_amount);
            $discounted_amount = empty($product->discounted_amount)?0:($product->discounted_amount);
            $total_quantity = empty($product->product_quantity)?0:($product->product_quantity);
            $product_ordered = empty($product->product_ordered)?0:($product->product_ordered);
            $quantity_available = $total_quantity - $product_ordered;
            $subtotal = $price*$quantity;
            $count++;
            ?>
            <tr class="calc">
            <td title="Ingredients: <?php echo $product->ingredients; ?>"><?php echo $product->name; ?></td>
            <td title="Reason for price change:" <?php echo !empty($product->product_message)?' '.$product->product_message.'"':''; ?>>
                <input style="width:100%; text-align:right; padding-right:5px;"  type="text" name="paid_product_price[]" class="price paidShowMessage" value="<?php echo $price; ?>">
                <input type="text" class="paid_product_message" name="paid_product_message[]" value="<?php echo $product->product_message; ?>">
            </td>
            <td title="Reason for discount:" <?php echo !empty($product->product_dmessage)?' '.$product->product_dmessage.'"':''; ?>>
                <input style="width:100%; text-align:right; padding-right:5px;"  type="text" name="paid_product_dscnt[]" class="dscnt spidEdit paidShowDMessage" value="<?php echo $discount; ?>">
                <!--<input type="text" name="paid_product_dscnt[]" class="dscnt spidEdit" value="<?php //echo $discount; ?>" data-min="0"  data-max="<?php //echo $product->max; ?> ">-->
                <input type="text" class="paid_product_dmessage" name="paid_product_dmessage[]" value="<?php echo $product->product_dmessage; ?>">
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="paid_product_dscnt_amt[]" class="dscnt_amt spidEdit" value="<?php echo $discount_amount; ?>" data-min="0"  data-max="<?php echo $product->max; ?> "></td>
            <td ><input type="hidden" name="paid_product_id[]" value="<?php echo $product->product_id; ?>"><input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $quantity_available; ?>" class="qa">                
            <input  type="text"  name="paid_product_qty[]" onkeyup="backOrder(<?php echo $count; ?>)" class="qty spinEdit" value="<?php echo $quantity; ?>" data-min="0"  data-max="<?php echo $product->max; ?>" ></td><!--data-min="0"-->
            <td><input  type="text" class="bo spidEdit" id="quav_<?php echo $count; ?>" value="<?php echo $quantity_available;?>"></td>
            <td title="Back Order Quantity:">
            <input style="width:100%; text-align:right; padding-right:5px;" id="qupe_<?php echo $count; ?>" type="text" name="paid_product_bo[]" class="boShowMessage" value=""></td>

            <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:5px;"><input type="text" class="total" name="paid_product_dscnted_amt[]" value="<?php echo $discounted_amount; ?>" readonly></td>
            </tr>


            <?php } ?>


<script>
function backOrder(id)
{

var quav = document.getElementById("quav_" + id);
var qupe = document.getElementById("qupe_" + id);
qupe.value = -1 * (quav.value);

}
</script>
```

Comment: While the OP ticked the checkmark, code dumps are not *useful* answers. Say *what* you changed, and *why*.

Comment: I have made all the id unique by adding integer to the id and accessed through that id..

Answer (score 1):

You can't have multiple elements with the same ID. You have to use `class` attribute, and in JavaScript select the elements using `document.getElementsByClassName()` and iterate over them.

Comment: I had initially done that, but it didn't help, It wasn't loading at all

Answer (score 1):

`id` values **must** be unique in the document. If you have to use something to idenitfy multiple elements, don't use an `id`. Other things you could use are `class` or any `data-*` attribute.

If using class, you'd use `querySelectorAll(".the-class")` or `getElementsByClassName("the-class")` and loop over the resulting collection. If using a `data-*` attribute, you'd use `querySelectorAll('[data-attr-name="attr-value"]')` and, again, loop over the resulting collection.

For example, your rows have class `calc`, and so we can use that and look within each row for the `qupe` and `quav`:

```js
function backOrder() {
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".calc"), function(row) {
    var quav = row.querySelector(".quav");
    var qupe = row.querySelector(".qupe");
    qupe.value = -1 * quav.value;
  });
}
backOrder();
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="calc">
      <td>
        <label>
          Quav 1
          <input type="text" class="quav" value="1">
        </label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label>
          Qupe 1
          <input type="text" class="qupe" value="1">
        </label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="calc">
      <td>
        <label>
          Quav 2
          <input type="text" class="quav" value="2">
        </label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label>
          Qupe 2
          <input type="text" class="qupe" value="2">
        </label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="calc">
      <td>
        <label>
          Quav 3
          <input type="text" class="quav" value="3">
        </label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label>
          Qupe 3
          <input type="text" class="qupe" value="3">
        </label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Normally, though, when dealing with pairs of elements like that, it's best to identify a container they have in common.

Comment: Thanks for the help Sir, but I got it working through Aju John's Answer